# CSS - How to make a cone shape with gradient color

Tags: css

I'm trying to replicate the google map's marker that shows user facing direction. It has got a cone/light beam/flash light type of shape where it fades from a color to transparent.

[image]

When I google css shapes, this is one of suggested methods for creating a cone shape :

```css
.cone {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid #07CAF3;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cone"></div>
```

But because it's made of borders, I cannot apply a gradient to it.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conic-gradient combined with mask:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:conic-gradient(from -45deg at bottom,#0000, blue 1deg 90deg, #0000 91deg);
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#0000,#000);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

OR a radial-gradient one and the conic applied to mask:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom,blue ,#0000);
  -webkit-mask:conic-gradient(from -45deg at bottom,#0000, #000 1deg 90deg, #0000 91deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: I think visually the second solution is more accurate to what I want to achieve. There is one tiny issue with both solutions though, the sides of cone looks jagged and it doesn't look pleasant to use. Any way to fix that?

Comment: @xperator check the update, you can add more value to the color stop and avoid have a hard stop

Answer (score 0):

The mask idea from @temaniafif is probably the best idea, but you could also have two background-images, and in the radial one play around with the color and the percentage offsets/opacities to get the effect you want:

```css
div {
  background-image: conic-gradient(transparent 0deg, transparent 45deg, white 45deg, white 315deg, transparent 315deg, transparent 360deg), radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2) 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 70%, transparent 80%);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 75vmin;
  height: 75vmin;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```